# On-prem SQL execute stored procedure in Logic App Standard

Tags: azure, azure-logic-app-standard

When executing a stored procedure using an in-app connector in Logic App Standard (Stateful), the procedure does not return data and continues running, even though it is successful according to application insights. However, if I try the same logic using a Function, it works. Also it's possible to get smaller amount of data using parameters so connection is ok.

I have configured the ServiceProviders.Sql.QueryTimeout to 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a store procedure to retrieve the name from database using Id parameter.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetUserNameByID
    @UserID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Name
    FROM [dbo].[Test] 
    WHERE Id = @UserID;
END;
```

**workflow**-

[image]

I am able to get the value in output.

[image]

Try to check connection string, you will get the output.

Comment: Connection string is ok. I am able to get less amount of data using parameters.

Comment: what is the size of the data you are trying to fetch using procedure?

Comment: about 10-15mb max.

Comment: Can you share your output screenshot?

Comment: During execution of Logic App, it appears that the stored procedure is running. However, when checking the application insights, it indicates that the process has already been successfully executed. I have also tried to write output to file but same think Logic App "bugs" to stored procedure process.

Comment: is it failing or succeeding? You can check it in trigger history

Comment: it's just running.

Comment: can you share the screenshot when its running?

Comment: There is no information that would help.